# How to create multiple objects in a loop in Parse.com SDK?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to create several objects in a loop in Parse's Javascript SDK.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    var user = results[i],
        newPuzzle = new Puzzle();
    newPuzzle.set("userAsked", user);
    newPuzzle.save();
}
```

But it works only for several objects (from 2 to 5) and then falls to response. I found method  *Parse.Object.saveAll(list, options)* but it doesn't work for creating AFAIK - only for updating.

I also used local function written on pure Node.js with Parse's master key - it can save objects in a loop and works perfectly. But I need working with filesystem and local JavaScript for me is a headache.

How can I create multiple objects in one request in Parse's SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly is this failing? I believe this should work. Be aware that `newPuzzle.save()` is an asynchronous operation that does not complete instantaneous. You should pass in a success and an error callback function to a) wait until all save operations complete and b) be sure they complete successfully (or what the error is, if they fail). Also see the [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-saving)

Comment: @DanielBaulig Thanks for the comment. Saving doesn't fail, it works but only several times. And also callback doesn't log anything, not quite sure why.
newPuzzle.save(null, {success: function(ob){console.log(obj);}})

Comment: Save is async and returns a Promise. You need to collect the promises in an array and then wait for them to complete with a when I believe.

Comment: @yablokoff: So if you invoke `newPuzzle.save(null, { success: function() { console.log('SUCCESS', arguments); ), error: function () { console.log('ERROR', arguments); } })` neither callback function will be eventually invoked for some save operations? If so, this is a bug and you should file it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use saveAll function

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.saveAll

You will need to create an array of objects you wish to save first and pass as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use, `saveAll` function, see example below:

```
var TimelineEvent = Parse.Object.extend("Timeline");

exports.processNotifications = function (notifications, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var timelineEvents = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
    var notification = notifications[i];
    if (notification.hasOwnProperty("timelineEvent")) {
      var timelineEvent = new TimelineEvent();
      timelineEvent.set("eventNotificationKey", notification.notificationKey);
      timelineEvent.set("isDevelopmentAccount", notification.isDebugOnly);
      timelineEvent.set("eventName", notification.timelineEvent.name);
      timelineEvent.set("eventDescription", notification.timelineEvent.description);
      timelineEvent.set("eventValue", notification.timelineEvent.value);
      timelineEvent.set("channel", notification.channel);
      timelineEvents.push(timelineEvent);
    }
  }
  Parse.Object.saveAll(timelineEvents, {
    success:successCallback,
    error:failureCallback
  });
};
```